# How to show prices in vnd in PHP?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have an `input` to display price:

```
<input type='text' name='price' value='1000000'/>
```

I want to show `1,000,000`.

Comment: You could write your own js or use a prewritten js lib for it. heres a couple ive googled http://numeraljs.com/ and https://formatjs.io/  The benefit of a js implementation means even when you edit the textbox the JS will reformat  your number instantly

Comment: Just to clear things up: are you talking about PHP here?

Comment: You’re buying into a lot of problems if you format numbers that way: (a) It is no longer a number, and you will need to re-process it if you want to do anything with it; (b) You will need to ensure that the user follows the format correctly, and that’s _very_ hard to do; (c) The comma (`,`) is not technically a correct thousands separator, and certainly not a universal one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for that:

```
$price = 1000000;
echo number_format($price, 0, '', ','); // 1,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format($number);
```

Otherwise you can modify the value as a string: '1,000,000'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `money_format()` for pricing conversation. It will Returns the formatted string. Characters before and after the formatting string will be returned unchanged. Non-numeric number causes returning NULL and emitting E_WARNING.
you can find more details from [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
money_format('%!.0n', 1000000)
output // 1,000,000
```

Comment: You have to [`setlocale()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and your output is wrong.